# Is there a more economical version of this powersource prototyper the CADET

Tags: prototyping, breadboard

This is what I want....problem is that they are expensive, really expensive ($500). Is there a more economical version?

http://tequipment.net/ELCADET2.html

http://tequipment.net/ProductImages/E&L/CADET2_mid.jpg
Features:

```
* Expanded Removeable breadboard area
* Two open collector pulsers
* Built-in multi-waveform function generator
* Quad voltage power supply: Three DC & one low voltage AC
* Functions with optional electronics trainer boards
* Built-in logic probe with pulse capture
* BCD to 7 segment decoder/display
* 8 channel logic indicatorsSpecifications
```

The C.A.D.E.T. II is a Complete Electronics Trainer that includes all the functions needed to teach basic AC/DC, Linear and Digital Electronics courses. The unit contains all the functions of our highly acclaimed original C.A.D.E.T. plus frequently requested features from educators worldwide.

The breadboard area is 33% larger than original C.A.D.E.T., holds up to 32 IC's and comes standard as a removable socket plate with velcro. If you prefer, it can be ordered withour bread boards for use with the extensive line of E&L Trainer Boards. The built-in logic probe will detect narrow logic pulses and eliminate the need for extra lab equipment. The BCD to 7 segment display/decoder saves students time when constucting circuits. The Quad Voltage Power Supply has +5 VDC, two variable DC outputs, and a fixed 12.6 VAC center tapped output. The trainer also includes 8 TTL compatible logic switches and two pulsers.

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: That's a pretty rich feature set.  I prefer my power supply and test equipment outboard; the rest of the features can be added to the breadboard as needed.  Given the availability of items like $50 logic analyzers (http://dangerousprototypes.com/open-logic-sniffer/) and $89 digital storage oscilloscopes (http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/micro-digital-storage-oscilloscopedso-nano-p-512.html) I'm not sure the all-in-one approach is practical if you want to go cheap.

Answer (score 3):

A similar but cheaper solution is [Global Specialties PB-501 Logic Design Trainer](http://www.tequipment.net/GlobalSpecialtiesPB-501.html) $182.70.

Answer (score 1):

Going with @Veuvius' suggestion of getting the parts

- The protoype board is Twin Industries [TW-E41-1060](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=438-1048-ND) $37.45.
- Logic probe BK Precision [DP 21](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=DP-21-ND) $37.00